# Lookup if cell contains text from lookup columns return third

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to lookup if a cell contains strings from two columns in a lookup table and return a category (third column of lookup table).

Cell examples:

```
abc 2021 Gross Profit abcd
ab 2022 Gross Profit ADJ abcde
ab ADJ 2021 Gross Profit abcde
cd 2023 Payroll asdf
dage Sales 2021 bce
2020 Payroll Revision abcdef
```

Output should be; respectivley:

| Cells Column | Output Column |
| --- | --- |
| abc 2021 Gross Profit abcd | Actual |
| ab 2022 Gross Profit ADJ abcde | Adjustment |
| ab ADJ 2021 Gross Profit abcde | Adjustment |
| cd 2023 Payroll asdf | Payroll |
| dage Sales 2021 bce | Sales |
| 2020 Payroll Revision abcdef | Payroll Revision |

Lookup table example [name: lookup_table]:

*Edit: Actual lookup table has hundreds of rows this is an example subset - the lookup table should remain an excel table so the reference range adjusts automatically when a new record is added to the lookup_table*

| Lookup1 | Lookup2 | Category1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gross Profit |  | Actual |
| Gross Profit | ADJ | Adjustment |
| Sales |  | Sales |
| COGS |  | Cost of Goods Sold |
| Payroll |  | Payroll |
| Payroll | Revision | Payroll Adjustment |

I am trying to use the following formula to return the category but it is returning a two value array and does not manage to retrieve the correct category:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(IFERROR(
    LET(cell,M3,
        lookup1_range,lookup_table[Lookup1],
        lookup2_range,lookup_table[Lookup2],
        category_range,lookup_table[Category1],
        contains_both,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup1_range,cell)), ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup2_range,cell))), 1, 0),
        contains_lookup1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup1_range,cell)),1,0),
        matches_lookup1,IF(contains_lookup1,MATCH(lookup1_range,lookup1_range,0),""),
        matches_both,IF(contains_both,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup2_range,INDEX(lookup1_range,matches_lookup1))),matches_lookup1,""),""),
        matches,IF(matches_both<>"",matches_both,matches_lookup1),
        lookup_value,IF(matches_both<>"", INDEX(category_range, matches_both, 1), IF(matches_lookup1<>"", INDEX(category_range, matches_lookup1, 1), "")),
        IF(lookup_value<>"",
            lookup_value,
            IF(matches_lookup1<>"",
                IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup2_range,cell)),
                    INDEX(category_range, matches_lookup1, 1),
                    INDEX(category_range, matches_lookup1, 1)),
                "")
        )
    ),
    ""
),IFERROR(
    LET(cell,M3,
        lookup1_range,lookup_table[Lookup1],
        lookup2_range,lookup_table[Lookup2],
        category_range,lookup_table[Category1],
        contains_both,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup1_range,cell)), ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup2_range,cell))), 1, 0),
        contains_lookup1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup1_range,cell)),1,0),
        matches_lookup1,IF(contains_lookup1,MATCH(lookup1_range,lookup1_range,0),""),
        matches_both,IF(contains_both,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup2_range,INDEX(lookup1_range,matches_lookup1))),matches_lookup1,""),""),
        matches,IF(matches_both<>"",matches_both,matches_lookup1),
        lookup_value,IF(matches_both<>"", INDEX(category_range, matches_both, 1), IF(matches_lookup1<>"", INDEX(category_range, matches_lookup1, 1), "")),
        IF(lookup_value<>"",
            lookup_value,
            IF(matches_lookup1<>"",
                IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(lookup2_range,cell)),
                    INDEX(category_range, matches_lookup1, 1),
                    INDEX(category_range, matches_lookup1, 1)),
                "")
        )
    ),
    ""
)<>""),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use COUNTIF combined with wildcards to count text matches:

[image]

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1;"*Gross Profit*")=0;"None";IF(COUNTIF(A1;"*ADJ*")=0;"Actual";"Adjustment"))
```

**UPDATE:** OP wants to relationate lookup table and data, so here's another approach using array formulas:

Because the formula is array, you must introduce it pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or it won't work!

[image]

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LOOKUPTABLE[Category1],SUMPRODUCT(MAX(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & LOOKUPTABLE[Lookup1] & "*")* COUNTIF(A1,"*" &LOOKUPTABLE[Lookup2]&"*")*ROW(LOOKUPTABLE[Category1])))-1),"None")
```

Anyways, I've uploaded a sample to Gdrive in case you want to check:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eJjNzKBw6nLsOkcMhfAK5NyObSgYrUc8/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=114417674018837700466&rtpof=true&sd=true

Notice there is a `-1` because the formulla returns the **absolute** row number. Because data on lookuptable starts at row 2, then you must add -1. If data started at row 5, instead of -1 you would need -4 and so on...

Comment: Is there a way not to harcode the lookup table in the formula? The actual lookup table has hundreds of rows

Comment: @Spaghetti ¿Is the lookup table always 2 columns? Can you edit your original question and add some extra data and some extra lookup table records? just for testing

Comment: @[Foxfire And Burns And Burns] More lookup_table records and use cases added along with an edit for clarification. I am using an excel table so the lookup_table range remains dynamic when a new record is added - lookup table will continue to keep this format: 2 columns lookup, 1 column category